# result looks incorrect when searching with parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I worked on ES 7.10.1, and I have following simple search query:

`GET /megacorp/_doc/_search?q=+last_name:"smith"  +first_name:"jane"`

I think I have specified the `and` condition, that mean: only both conditions are met, then the document will be queried out

but I got two documents back:

first:

```
  "first_name" : "Jane",
  "last_name" : "Smith",
```

second:

```
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : "Smith",
```

The second one only matches on the last_name, not on the first_name, I am not sure why this document is also queried out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with `must` clause which makes it easy to understand your query syntax, why you are working with Lucene syntax which is different to comprehend?

In your case, looks like its working as `OR` hence both the results are coming.

Comment: Sure, thanks, I know search api with request body, I am now learning ES and experimenting search api with query parameter...